# Column 'sender_id' cannot be null after db reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to fix a few new errors that occurred after I did a rake db:migrate:reset. I have fixed all of them, except for this one. For my custom inbox, after I click send for new message I get this error:

> Mysql2::Error: Column 'sender_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO
>   `messages` (`body`, `container`, `created_at`, `read_at`,
>   `recepient_deleted`, `recepient_id`, `sender_deleted`, `sender_id`,
>   `subject`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('test 1', 'draft', '2013-04-05
>   18:59:08', NULL, 0, 16, 0, NULL, 'test 1', '2013-04-05 18:59:08')

Now some background information. Before I did a reset I changed the migration. So maybe that is coming into play?

original migration:

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        create_table :messages do |t|
            t.string :sender_id,:null => false
            t.string :recepient_id
            t.boolean :sender_deleted, :recepient_deleted, :default => false
            t.string :subject,:null => false
            t.text :body
            t.datetime :read_at
            t.string :container,:default => "draft"
            t.timestamps
        end
    end

    def down
        drop_table :messages
    end
end
```

modified migration so I can change from string to integer:

```
class ChangeSenderIdAndRecepientIdColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :messages, :sender_id, :integer
    change_column :messages, :recepient_id, :integer
  end

  def down
     change_column :messages, :sender_id, :string
     change_column :messages, :recepient_id, :string
  end
end
```

messages controller:

```
  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.sender_id = @user_id
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent"
      redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward. Where does `@user_id` get set?

Comment: in the controller I had user_id, it was supposed to be user.id. I switch it before, but I guess when the reset happen it changed it back to user_id.

Comment: rake db:migrate:reset does not change anything in the controller.